# HERE SDK Lite iOS crash after entering background during initialization

Tags: ios, sdk, crash, here-api

We recently detected an App crash that seems related to HERE SDK Lite for iOS (version: 4.7.6). Basically it seems that the App went in background during `SDKNativeEngine` initialization. I didn't find any information in the API reference that inform that this activity should be performed preventing the App to going in background, so my guess is that it might be an unhandled edge case. Do you know if there are any specific workaround on this issue?

```
Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x10cf229f0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
0  heresdk                        0x52a444 (Missing)
1  heresdk                        0x5238e8 (Missing)
2  heresdk                        0x522d14 (Missing)
3  heresdk                        0xff4e0 (Missing)
4  heresdk                        0x142be0 (Missing)
5  heresdk                        0x13fc0c (Missing)
6  heresdk                        0x13f8cc (Missing)
7  heresdk                        0xa2dcc (Missing)
8  heresdk                        0x145a4 (Missing)
9  <REDACTED>                     0xb8b074 static SDKNativeEngine.main() + 4380340340
10 <REDACTED>                     0xb8ae50 HereService.init() + 4380339792
11 <REDACTED>                     0xb9204c static Module.warmup() + 4380368972
12 <REDACTED>                     0xb92070 @objc static Module.warmup() + 4380369008
```

This is basically the piece of code that is causing the issue:

```
let options = SDKOptions(accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
                                     accessKeySecret:accessKeySecret)

var nativeEngine: SDKNativeEngine
do {
   try nativeEngine = SDKNativeEngine(options: options)
} catch {
   assertionFailure("Failed to initialize SDKNativeEngine. Cause: \(error)")
   return nil
}
SDKNativeEngine.sharedInstance = nativeEngine
```

**Update - 2021-10-24**

I applied the suggested [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69496277/355465) but still getting very similar App crashes, this time involving `SDKNativeEngine.initalize()` function. The function is basically doing this:

```swift
static func initalize() throws {
   try SDKInitializer.initialize(options: sdkOptions)
}
```

I'll attach here a sample stack trace:

```
Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x159019c80 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
0  heresdk                        0x52a444 (Missing)
1  heresdk                        0x5238e8 (Missing)
2  heresdk                        0x522d14 (Missing)
3  heresdk                        0xff4e0 (Missing)
4  heresdk                        0x142be0 (Missing)
5  heresdk                        0x13fc0c (Missing)
6  heresdk                        0x13f8cc (Missing)
7  heresdk                        0xa2dcc (Missing)
8  heresdk                        0x145a4 (Missing)
9  heresdk                        0x144cc (Missing)
10 heresdk                        0x8da70 (Missing)
11 heresdk                        0x8c740 (Missing)
12 <REDACTED>                     0xbb288c static SDKNativeEngine.initalize() + 4316014732
13 <REDACTED>                     0xbb7cb4 static Module.warmup() + 4316036276
```

Comment: It appears to crash on your SBTAppDelegate didFînishLaunchingWithOptions method. What can of init are you doing there ? There is not much information in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much information to add. In the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I'm doing some other async operations for initing the app, but the stack trace seems to be heresdk related. Without symbols for the SDK is difficult to give additional info.

Comment: From what I saw in Here Sdk , the map init needs a frame : if your init is asynchronous, then the frame or the view containing frame may not be defined at this time . Depending on device performance or other load on the device, the view init may happens before or after here sdk init which may lead to this long of error.

Comment: Actually I'm not using the SDK for any map UI component, why should it requires a frame? And where you can see that it needs a frame? Is it detailed in the API docs?

Comment: Found the map init [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-lite/4.8.2.0/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html)

Comment: I thought that from the stack trace was clear that I'm not initing MapViewLite(frame:. But for sake of clarity I'll ad more information.

Comment: I send you aomw info in chat

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not seem to initialize the HERE SDK. If you do *not* show a map view you either need to call `SDKInitializer.initializeIfNecessary()` yourself, or when you want to set credentials, call:

```
do {
    try SDKInitializer.initialize(options: sdkOptions)
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to initialize HERE SDK. Cause: \(error)")
}
```

The code from your question can be used to reset options for an already initialized HERE SDK. I took this information from the latest [HERE SDK documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-lite/4.9.0.0/dev_guide/topics/key-concepts.html#engines).

Comment: I updated and released the code following your suggestion, but we're still getting the same issue. Luckily It seem to not happening too much frequently but still a crash that probably should be fixed.